# Sum of an infinite geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

BdMO Nationals 12:

> Each room of the Magic Castle has exactly one exit door.The rooms are 
>   designed such that when you can go from one room to the next one 
>   through a door, the second room's length is equal to the first room's width, and the second room's width is 
>   half of the first room's length. Each door can be used only once. Magic Prince has entered 
>   the castle and now needs to get out. To get out of each room, the prince needs time equal to the width of 
>   the room. The prince has to use each door to get out of the castle. However,the 
>   prince can become as small as he wants (so that he can go into even very small rooms). If the castle is a 
>   square of side length $20$ meters then how long will it take for the prince to get out?

I am facing a problem here.Since there are infinite number of rooms,can he ever get out?Since the prince has to start from the innermost room[or that's how I interpreted it],can we conclude that the outermost room has length 20 m and breadth  10 m?A picture was given and it seems so.Nevertheless,here is my try:

The width of the outermost room is 10 m.

The width of the next room then is also 10 m.

The width of the subsequent rooms are 5,5,$\dfrac{5}{2},\dfrac{5}{2}$.......

Summing up,

$2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{10\left(\dfrac{1}{2} \right)^i}$

which is just 40[unless I have made a mistake in my calculations]. Therefore,the Prince would require 40 units of time to get out.Am I right?

EDIT: A sketch of the situation can be found [here](http://matholympiad.org.bd/questions/bdmo-questions/summary/4-bdmo-2012/21-bdmo-2012-national-primary).

Comment: I think the prince has an even bigger problem. If every room has only one door, isn't he trapped in the room he starts in + the adjacent room?

Comment: @Arthur,yes,it seems so.Any advice on rephrasing the question?

Comment: Does every room have *two* doors, so that you can either go back or into the next room?

Comment: @Arthur,yes.I think I should write 'each room has exactly one **Exit** door.'

Comment: I have looked up the question (with the sketch). Now I finally understand the problem. I have edited in a link.

Comment: There is clearly an error (already in the linked version). It should say: "the second room's length is equal to the first room's width, and the second room's width is half of the first room's LENGTH."

Comment: @Phira Where is the mistake?

Comment: @rah4927 The problem statement says: "the second room's length is equal to the first room's width, and the second room's width is half of the first room's width." but the sketch makes it clear that the last "width" should be "length".

Comment: @Phira,yes,it would seem so.The question is very badly posed,and the picture does nothing but to confuse the students even more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. It takes 40 units of time to get out of the castle. I have to say that, even with the sketch, the question is very badly posed.

Comment: Yes,but when talking about something real,we can't just say the number of rooms just converge to some number X.There will be an infinite number of rooms.So the Prince should never actually be able to get out.Where is the flaw in my logic?IS it because,no matter the number of rooms,the Prince's main goal is to get out of a square with finite area?So he will always be able to get out?

Comment: The flaw is assuming that a Magic Castle can only have finitely many rooms ;)